# Web API running under IIS

Tags: c#, iis

I have a web client and a web API.  When running IIS express I am able to connect to the API from the client and everything works fine.  When I moved the client and API to run under IIS I can no longer connect.  Is there something different that I need to configure to make it work?

Comment: By the client, do you mean a browser hitting the api on localhost, a client application on the same machine or a client application on a different machine?

Comment: Client is web based application written in C# and Angular.  Client and API are both running on the same machine.

Comment: URL will be different because IISExpress always runs on a higher port. If the port is included in your target URI, it will need to be removed/replaced with the port that the IIS application listens on.

Comment: That might be the problem